# CORS problems with Ktor on Heroku but not on local

Tags: kotlin, heroku, cors, ktor

So I just deployed my app on Heroku. I have an application where the front end sends a log in request to the back end. But I cant get rid of the CORS problem on the Heroku side (no problem on the local side).

My frontend is on `https://yourclimbfrontend.herokuapp.com/`

And this is how I adjust my CORS:

```
fun Application.configureHTTP() {
    install(CORS) {
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Options)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Put)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Delete)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Get)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Patch)
        allowHeader(HttpHeaders.Authorization)
        allowHeader("cart_session")
        exposeHeader("cart_session")
        allowHeader("MyCustomHeader")
        allowHeader("X-Requested-With")
        allowHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override")
        allowHeader("Content-Type")
        allowHeader("Authorization")
        allowHeader("Accept")
        allowHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
        allowHeader("Accept")
        allowHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        allowHost("https://yourclimbfrontend.herokuapp.com")
      //  allowHost("localhost:3000")'
       // anyHost()

    }
}
```

It works on my local machine if I have the `localHost:3000` on and it works on the Heroku side if I have the `anyHost()` on. But I have read that one should avoid `anyHost()` so Im trying to only let `https://yourclimbfrontend.herokuapp.com` send requests.

Am I using the wrong link some how in the `allowHost`? Or do I need additional lines for allowing Heroku?

Comment: You can remove the `allowMethod(HttpMethod.Get)` since GET method is added by default on CORS plugin installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be intuitive, but Ktor's CORS middleware [expects you to specify the allowed hosts separately from the associated scheme(s)](https://ktor.io/docs/cors.html#hosts). Accordingly, instead of

```kotlin
install(CORS) {
  // omitted
  allowHost("https://yourclimbfrontend.herokuapp.com")
  // omitted
}
```

```kotlin
install(CORS) {
  // omitted
  allowHost("yourclimbfrontend.herokuapp.com", schemes = listOf("https"))
  // omitted
}
```

Besides, you can safely drop the following two lines from your CORS config

```kotlin
allowHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
allowHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
```

as those two headers are *response* headers, not *request* headers.